# Looping over an object is not taking element by element in apps script

Tags: google-apps-script

I have an array and a dictionary object, I want to check if the elements in the array are present in the object key and if not present then move the last not matched value from object into a new array.

If the last value itself is a match then move the value in another array

array is

```
var Concat_names = [a, b, c]
```

object is

```
var Concat_rows = {a=D45, d=D64, e=D72, f=D90}
```

I tried the below

```
var Last_CellnoMatch = []
var Lact_CellisMatch = []

  for (var x in Concat_names){
    for (var key in Concat_rows){
      if(key!=Concat_names[x]){
        Last_CellnoMatch.push(Concat_rows[key]); 
        Logger.log(Last_CellnoMatch);
      }  
    }
  }
Logger.log(Cell);
```

I want `Last_CellnoMatch` to get the last value in the object where its a no match as "D90"in to and if last value is a match then move the last value into a new array `Lact_CellisMatch`

Please help me achieve this, Thank you!

Comment: About `get the last value in the object where its a no match as "D90"`, can I ask you about the detailed logic for retrieving "D90" from `var Concat_names = [a, b, c]` and `var Concat_rows = {a=D45, d=D64, e=D72, f=D90}`?

Comment: so 
1. every element in ```Concat_names ``` should be checked in every key in object ```Concat_rows```, when there is no match the first array should get the value of the last key in the object. 
2. If the last key in the object is a match then also get into a second array the value of that last matched key. 
3. However, if there is a match in any key then get all the keys which are a no match in to the first array.

hope I was clear

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I couldn't understand the logic for retrieving "D90" from `var Concat_names = [a, b, c]` and `var Concat_rows = {a=D45, d=D64, e=D72, f=D90}`. But, I would like to support you. When I could correctly understand the logic, I would like to think of a solution.

Comment: Thank you @Tanaike-san, I really appreciate your help, can we loop over ```Concat_names``` and check in ```Concat_rows```, and if no match, we can take length of ```Concat_rows``` and take the last element as the key and then ```Concat_rows[key]```

Comment: Thank you for replying. Can I ask you about the detailed logic for retrieving "D90" from `var Concat_names = [a, b, c]` and `var Concat_rows = {a=D45, d=D64, e=D72, f=D90}`? From your reply, I cannot still understand this logic. I apologize for this, again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, your object is built wrong. I scribbled a possible solution for you:

```js
var Concat_names = ["a", "b", "c"];
var Concat_rows = {a: "D45",d: "D64",e: "D72",f: "D90"};
var Last_CellnoMatch = [];
var Last_CellMatch = []

  var keys = Object.keys(Concat_rows);
  var last_value_match = "";
  var last_value_no_match = "";
  for (var key of keys) {
    if (Concat_names.indexOf(key) == -1) {
      last_value_no_match = Concat_rows[key];
    } else {
      last_value_match = Concat_rows[key];
    }
  }
  if (last_value_no_match != "") Last_CellnoMatch.push(last_value_no_match);
  if (last_value_match != "") Last_CellMatch.push(last_value_match);
  console.log(Last_CellnoMatch);
  console.log(Last_CellMatch);
```